# Progress for a HTTP response that takes a long time to process

Tags: ajax, json, sockets, http

I have a request to return an array of JSON object (requested by AJAX call in an AngularJS web app), which represent certain files on the server (node.js). 
Most of the time the result is stored in a database so the response is very quick.

However if the database hasn't been filled, or the files have changed, then the files need to be parsed (this includes the server making requests to 3rd party web services) and (stored in the database) and then be sent to the client.

This can take 10 seconds and longer depending on how many files there are.

Currently the web browser will just wait for the response, and I have a separate WebSocket to communicate progress of the parsing to a progress bar on the web page. However it seems quite feasible that the web browser will timeout if there are many files on the server.

So it seems that if the parsing is required I should just return a response immediately and get the client to request after it is told the parsing is complete (via the WebSocket). What is a suitable response for this? 202 Accepted? Or perhaps 426 Upgrade Required (to WebSocket)?

Or is there a way of sending progress over HTTP and not use WebSockets at all? (Something like streaming the HTTP Headers with a Percent complete header and then send the json in the body, or will the web browser timeout if it takes to long to get the body of the response)

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas, there might be more ways:

- There is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), where your page does not have a fixed size and gets continuously updated with some script area which then gets immediately executed. I would consider it more a hack, but it works.
- Then you could have some XMLHTTPRequest which polls the server to get a status update and displays the current value.
- You can do similar things without JavaScript, if you reload the same page again and again using a meta-refresh header with some seconds refresh time. On the server side you update the page continuously with the current status or just create it on demand.